# ActionExecutingContext.IsChildAction equivalent in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently porting a MVC 5 app that require to detect if the current controller action is not a "child action".

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction) {
            // Do something if not a child action
        }
    }   
}
```

Is there another way to do it in MVC Core ? or is there a redesign in MVC Core that disable this "notion" ?

Comment: Child Actions aren't part of Asp.NET Mvc Core. It should be safe to remove the if from your filter.

Comment: I will take your advice. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

I finally found more information about MVC 6 `Child Actions` replacement here: [Goodbye Child Actions, Hello View Components](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/01/02/goodbye-child-actions-hello-view-components.aspx)

Hope it will help someone.